# RoR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was using the following piece of code without any issues. the function `querytags` returns a set of "products". `geturl` function checks if a product has an image associated with it. All products with an image are pushed to `productsProxy` array

```
@query = params[:tag]
@products = queryTags(@query)
@productsProxy = Array.new

if @products != nil
    @products.each do |p|
        tempProduct = ProductProxy.new(p)
        if tempProduct.getUrl(tempProduct.images[0]['id'], 'small', tempProduct.images[0]['file'])
        @productsProxy.push(tempProduct)
        end
    end
else
    @productProxy = []
end
```

Then i tried to add another parameter in the URL and changed the `querytags` function accordingly.

```
@query = params[:tag]
@taxon = params[:taxon]
@products = queryTags(@query, @taxon)
@productsProxy = Array.new

if @products != nil
    @products.each do |p|
        tempProduct = ProductProxy.new(p)
        if tempProduct.getUrl(tempProduct.images[0]['id'], 'small', tempProduct.images[0]['file'])             #now showing error
        @productsProxy.push(tempProduct)
        end
    end
else
    @productProxy = []
end
```

But I stated getting `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` on the line:

```
if tempProduct.getUrl(tempProduct.images[0]['id'], 'small', tempProduct.images[0]['file'])
```

I checked with the help of debugger that `@products` array is not empty. I am unable to figure out why suddenly i am getting this error. please can someone help

Comment: It's not about the "@products" array being empty or not - if it was empty, the "@products" iterator wouldn't do anything. The problem is that one of your products is either lacking an images attribute or the images[0] is not returning a hash. For debugging purposes I'd start by adding "break if p.images.nil?" to the top of your iterator and go from there.

Comment: Not a problem, I added my comment as an answer if you want to accept it so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the "@products" array being empty or not - if it was empty, the "@products" iterator wouldn't do anything. The problem is that one of your products is either lacking an images attribute or the images[0] is not returning a hash. For debugging purposes I'd start by adding "break if p.images.nil?" to the top of your iterator and go from there.